# Upload form with properties using HTML or bootstrap form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

Normally, we can edit a document properties after the document was uploaded.

Is there a way to use something similar to `<form>` to complete all the required fields at the same time the form is uploaded to a library?

I currently have the form and a way to select a local file to be uploaded but can't figure out how to actually get the file and properties to a library...

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 90px">
<input id="docTitle" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Document Name or Title">
<select id="docCategory" class="form-control">
    <option>Guideline</option>
    <option>Instructions</option>
    <option>Plan</option>
    <option>Policy</option>
    <option>Procedure</option>
    <option>Source File</option>
    <option>Standard</option>
    <option>Template</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">File to upload</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="getFile">
</div>
<button id="addFileButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT**
I found below site after much research and was able to upload the file in SPO. I just need to figure out how to apply the properties. 
[How To Upload Document In Document Library Using JSOM In Sharepoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-uploads-document-in-document-library-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013-o365)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upload files with properties using REST API. The following code for your reference.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        init();
    });
});

function init()
{
    $("#btnUploadFiles").click(function(){
        var files=$("#inputTypeFiles")[0].files;
        uploadFiles(files[0]); // uploading singe file
    });
}

function uploadFiles (uploadFileObj) {
    var fileName = uploadFileObj.name;
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var documentLibrary="SampleDocuments";
    var folderName = "Folder1";
    var targetUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/" + documentLibrary + "/" + folderName;
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@target)/Files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + fileName + "')?$expand=ListItemAllFields&amp;amp;@target='" + targetUrl + "'";

    uploadFileToFolder(uploadFileObj, url, function (data) {
        var file = data.d;
        var updateObject = {
            __metadata: {
                type: file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.type
            },
            Column1: 'Test Data',   //meta data column1
            Column2: 'Test Data'    //meta data column2
        };

        url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('"+documentLibrary+"')/items(" + file.ListItemAllFields.Id + ")";

        updateFileMetadata(url, updateObject, file, function (data) {
            alert("File uploaded &amp;amp; meta data updation done successfully");
        }, function (data) {
            alert("File upload done but meta data updating FAILED");
        });
    }, function (data) {
        alert("File uploading and meta data updating FAILED");
    });
}

function getFileBuffer(uploadFile) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadFile);
    return deferred.promise();
}

function uploadFileToFolder(fileObj, url, success, failure) {
    var apiUrl = url;
    var getFile = getFileBuffer(fileObj);
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function updateFileMetadata(apiUrl, updateObject, file, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(updateObject),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "MERGE",
            "IF-MATCH": file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.etag,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Reference**:

[Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)

[Upload a file into document library using REST API in SharePoint 2013 / Online](https://sharepointmates.com/2017/07/20/upload-a-file-into-document-library-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013-online/)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work following the link I posted on my original message, and tweaked it a bit to apply the properties:

**readFile()**

I added all the variables from from the `<input>` fields, then passed the value to the **uploadFile()** function

```
var docTitle = $("#docTitle").val();
var docCategory = $("#docCategory").val();
```

**uploadFile()**

Used `.get_listItemAllFields()` to apply the value from `<input>` to the library document properties:

```
    //Update file properties
    var docProp = uploadedDocument.get_listItemAllFields();
    docProp.set_item("Title", docTitle);
    docProp.set_item("Category", docCategory);
    docProp.update();
```

**Complete code**

```
var fileInput; 
var fileName;
var docTitle;
var docCategory;

$(document).ready(function () {  
    fileInput = $("#getFile");  
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);  
});  

function registerClick() {  
    //Register File Upload Click Event   
    $("#addFileButton").click(readFile);  
}  

var arrayBuffer;  

function readFile() {  
    var fileVal = $("#getFile").val();
    var docTitle = $("#docTitle").val();
    var docCategory = $("#docCategory").val();

    //Get File Input Control and read th file name  
    var element = document.getElementById("getFile");  
    var file = element.files[0];  
    var parts = element.value.split("\\");  
        fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    //Read File contents using file reader  
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function (e) {  
        uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName, docTitle, docCategory);  
    }  
    reader.onerror = function (e) {  
        alert(e.target.error);  
    }  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);  
}  
var attachmentFiles; 
var siteUrl = '/sites/xxx/forms';

function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName, docTitle, docCategory) {  
    //Get Client Context,Web and List object.  
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');  

    //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
    var i, length, out = '';  
    for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1) {  
        out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
    }  
    var base64 = btoa(out);  

    //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
    var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
    createInfo.set_content(base64); 
    createInfo.set_overwrite(true); //want to overwrite the file with same name
    createInfo.set_url(fileName);  

    //Add the file to the library  
    var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo);  

    //Update file properties
    var docProp = uploadedDocument.get_listItemAllFields();
    docProp.set_item("Title", docTitle);
    docProp.set_item("Category", docCategory);
    docProp.update();

    //Load client context and execcute the batch 
    clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySucceeded, QueryFailed); 
}  

function QuerySucceeded() {
    console.log('File uploaded successfully');
    alert('File uploaded successfully');
}  

function QueryFailed(sender, args) {  
    console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());  
    alert("Request failed with error message - " + args.get_message() + " . Stack Trace - " + args.get_stackTrace());  
}
```